# Backup of files stored on ec2 instance to s3

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am not able to SSH into my ec2 instance, even after booting another instance from the AMI of the current instance.
The SSH verbose logs of the SSH command are:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 52.45.XXX.XXX [52.45.XXX.XXX] port 22.
```

And it gets stuck and gives timeout after few seconds. I am using the correct key and command for sure.

Is there a way I can access the files stored on the ec2 instance? Maybe, backing them up to s3 using the AWS console. I have sudo access of AWS console UI. How can I recover my data using AWS console UI? Or any other way to get the data or to SSH into the instance?

Answer (score 1):

If the files are on an EBS volume then detach the volume and attach it to another server which you can connect to. If the files are on an instance store then you can't recover them.